# Array problem for a quiz app with different subjects

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, arraylist

I found a bug for my quiz game app but i don't know what's causing it or how to fix it. All of the questions and choices are collected inside of an array and once the scene starts the script is working.

it works just fine, questions and the choices appear as it should do.

what i want to do is fix this bug I'm having but i don't know where to start and i would like some help

since i'm trying to figure out what's going on and have no conclusion to why it's happening, i tried to remake the whole script and tried to recreate the same thing or something similar from start to finish and i still got the same result. Idk maybe i'm just approaching it wrong

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Questions 
{
    public string question;
    public string answer;
}
```

Manager

```
public class Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    /*Calls Questions.cs
     *Creates an array and calls it [questions]
     *Creates a List and calls it [unansweredQuestions] with the format of
     *Questions.cs
     *Creates a private variable and calls it [currentQuestion]
     */
    public Questions[] questions; 
    public static List<Questions> unansweredQuestions;
    public static Questions currentQuestion;

    [SerializeField]
    public Text questionText;
    //gameObject
    public Text firstChoiceanswer;
    public Text secondChoiceanswer;
    //gameObject's text
    public Text A1;
    public Text A2;


    [SerializeField]
    public float TimeBetweenQuestions = 1f;
    //waits a few seconds

    void Start()
    {
        if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
        {
            unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Questions>();   
        }
        SetCurrentQuestion();
    }

    void SetCurrentQuestion()
    {
        int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, unansweredQuestions.Count);
        currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions[randomQuestionIndex];

        //Random position where the choices will go buttons
        int randomAnswerIndex = Random.Range(0, 2);

        if(randomAnswerIndex == 0)
        {
            A1.text = currentQuestion.answer;
            A2.text = currentQuestion.wronganswer;
        } else if (randomAnswerIndex == 1)
        {
            A2.text = currentQuestion.answer;
            A1.text = currentQuestion.wronganswer;
        }
        //changes the text with a random question
        questionText.text = currentQuestion.question;
    }

    //Checks the answer in A1
    public void AnswerChecking1()
    {
        if (currentQuestion.answer == firstChoiceanswer.text)
        {
            Debug.Log("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Wrong");
        }
        WaitTransitionToNextQuestion();
        LoadNextQuestion();
    }

    //Checks the answer in A2
    public void AnswerChecking2()
    {
        if (currentQuestion.answer == secondChoiceanswer.text)
        {
            Debug.Log("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Wrong");
        }
        WaitTransitionToNextQuestion();
        LoadNextQuestion();
    }

    //waits for abit to change question
    IEnumerator WaitTransitionToNextQuestion()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeBetweenQuestions);
    }

    //Changes the Question after answered
    public void LoadNextQuestion()
    {
        SetCurrentQuestion();
    }
}
```

The menu holds at least 4 different subject, the user has to choose from those 4 and then it transfer the user to a different scene for that subject.

This problem appears whenever I start a new game and select a subject (for ex. math), whenever I go back to the subject selection and click a different subject (ex. english), instead of showing new questions and choices, previous subject's (the first subject) questions and choices are still appearing instead of the new selected subject and I don't know why it's doing that.

Comment: None of the code here deals with the "pick a subject" part of your program. You know. The part where the problem is.

Comment: I will make an assumption that Start() is called when you change subjects. The fact that unansweredQuestions is static means that the list likely still contains items (as I don't see you removing Questions from that list anywhere). Therefore the count will not be 0 and the new questions will not be loaded.

Comment: @Draco18s the pick a subject is just a button that leads to a different scene

Comment: @TroyMac1ure so from what i'm getting from your comment i need to empty out that list so that its count is equals to 0, so how do i do that?
i can't just put ```unansweredQuestions = null``` at the start first before the if statement proceeds right?

Comment: You could also stop using `static` because whatever reason you have for making that field static is wrong.